# How can I extend a class in a particular condition?

Tags: java, if-statement, subclass, superclass

how can I make class X extends class Y in a particular condition? like I have a Super class Person and have an attribute age, another class called Adult, class Adult extends Person if the age is between 12 and 20? If it is not possible, do you have alternatives?

Comment: Class inheritance is a compile time concept.

Comment: One alternative is the factory pattern: http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-abstract-factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to implement what you are asking with `HAS-A` relationship and runtime polymorphism.

In below example, `Age` is a parent class containing more generalized properties for all age groups.

Different age groups are divided in several class. Those classes contains age specific code or properties and will extend `Age` class. For example `Young` and `Elder` class.

```
class Age {
    // Generalized code for Age class
}

class Young extends Age {
    // more specific code of Young class
}

class Elder extends Age {
    // Elder class specific code
}

public class test {
    Age age ; 
    int ageValue ;

    public Age returnVal(int ageValue){
        if (ageValue < 20) {
            age = new Young();
        } else { 
            age = new Elder();
        }

        // age object you get will be according to ageValue.
        return age;
    }
}
```

`returnVal()` method will return you the object of either `Young` class or `Elder`class according to `ageValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You might define a `Person` class with a `.isAdult()` instance method that returns a boolean, `true` if and only if the `Person` instance has `age` at least `12`. This seems simpler to me at least.